# When using hook_form_alter to modify a content type's node add / edit form, where do I put the #states property?

Tags: javascript

This is actually a compound question. All in all the question is:

**When using hook_form_alter to modify an existing content type's node add / edit form, where do I put the #states property, and, within the definition of the #state array, how do I determine what the value of 'name' should be in ':input[name="somename"]'?**

NOTE: If you're very familiar with using #states and modifying node add / edit forms, please skip to the very last of the question where my non-working sample code is listed.

I've created a custom content type and I would like to alter certain node add / edit form elements to show up conditionally based on the values in other fields. To do this, I'd like to use the #states property (Here is a [quick intro](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/using-the-drupal-7-form-api-states-system-to-create-conditions-between-form-elements/2014-01-20) where I first learned about #states).

Most of the examples and tutorials I find are about creating custom forms. But the same approach does not seem to be working when modifying existing custom content type node add / edit forms.

For example, notice in the link above the following:

```
$form['kids'] = array(
    '#title' => t('How many kids do you have?'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0, 1, 2),
  );

  $form['kids_preferences'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Your kids\' preference'),
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array('moto' => 'Motorcycles', 'cars' => 'Cars'),
     // Show this field only if the user has kids.
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        'input[name="marriage"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
      ),
      'disabled' => array(
        'select[name="kids"]' => array('value' => '0'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

One would think then, based on the above (which is the same in all other tutorials and Drupal Docs), that you'd add ['#states'] = array(etc..) immediately after the first field element key, right?

Looking at the 'disabled' definition, you'd also conclude that you'd use the field key (kids) to reference the value in the 'name=' part of the #states array, correct?

So, after doing dpm($form) I indeed found my field names. According to dpm they were $form["myfield1"] and $form["myfield2"].

So because $form['myfield2'] depends on a value in $form['myfield1'], I tried:

```
$form['field_rf_which_state_territory']['#states'] = array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="myfield1"]' => array('value' => 'Yes')
            ),
        );
```

However, that doesn't work. **Why?**

After doing a lot of digging only, I started to see references to array structures like `$form['myfield1']['und']['0']['#states']`

I don't understand that, but I gave it a shot. Here are the actual data dumps of the two form elements from my content type node add form that I need to interact. (sorry for the long dump)

1) `print_r($form["field_rf_which_state_territory"]);`

```
Array
(
[#type] => container
[#attributes] => Array
    (
        [class] => Array
            (
                [0] => field-type-list-text
                [1] => field-name-field-rf-which-state-territory
                [2] => field-widget-options-select
            )

    )

[#weight] => 15
[#tree] => 1
[#language] => und
[und] => Array
    (
        [#entity] => stdClass Object
            (
                [uid] => 1
                [name] => admin
                [type] => snaped_resource_finder
                [language] => und
                [title] => 
                [status] => 1
                [promote] => 1
                [sticky] => 0
                [created] => 1396239314
                [revision] => 
                [comment] => 2
                [menu] => Array
                    (
                        [link_title] => 
                        [mlid] => 0
                        [plid] => 0
                        [menu_name] => main-menu
                        [weight] => 0
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [module] => menu
                        [expanded] => 0
                        [hidden] => 0
                        [has_children] => 0
                        [customized] => 0
                        [parent_depth_limit] => 8
                    )

            )

        [#entity_type] => node
        [#bundle] => snaped_resource_finder
        [#field_name] => field_rf_which_state_territory
        [#language] => und
        [#field_parents] => Array
            (
            )

        [#columns] => Array
            (
                [0] => value
            )

        [#title] => Which State / Territory
        [#description] => 
        [#required] => 
        [#delta] => 0
        [#type] => select
        [#default_value] => Array
            (
            )

        [#multiple] => 
        [#options] => Array
            (
                [_none] => - None -
                [AL] => Alabama
                [AK] => Alaska
                [AZ] => Arizona
                [AR] => Arkansas
                [CA] => California
                [CO] => Colorado
                [CT] => Connecticut
                [DE] => Delaware
                [DC] => District Of Columbia
                [FL] => Florida
                [GA] => Georgia
                [HI] => Hawaii
                [ID] => Idaho
                [IL] => Illinois
                [IN] => Indiana
                [IA] => Iowa
                [KS] => Kansas
                [KY] => Kentucky
                [LA] => Louisiana
                [ME] => Maine
                [MD] => Maryland
                [MA] => Massachusetts
                [MI] => Michigan
                [MN] => Minnesota
                [MS] => Mississippi
                [MO] => Missouri
                [MT] => Montana
                [NE] => Nebraska
                [NV] => Nevada
                [NH] => New Hampshire
                [NJ] => New Jersey
                [NM] => New Mexico
                [NY] => New York
                [NC] => North Carolina
                [ND] => North Dakota
                [OH] => Ohio
                [OK] => Oklahoma
                [OR] => Oregon
                [PA] => Pennsylvania
                [RI] => Rhode Island
                [SC] => South Carolina
                [SD] => South Dakota
                [TN] => Tennessee
                [TX] => Texas
                [UT] => Utah
                [VT] => Vermont
                [VA] => Virginia
                [WA] => Washington
                [WV] => West Virginia
                [WI] => Wisconsin
                [WY] => Wyoming
            )

        [#value_key] => value
        [#element_validate] => Array
            (
                [0] => options_field_widget_validate
            )

        [#properties] => Array
            (
                [strip_tags] => 1
                [optgroups] => 1
                [empty_option] => option_none
                [filter_xss] => 
            )

        [#after_build] => Array
            (
                [0] => field_form_element_after_build
            )

    )

[#access] => 1
)
```

2) `print_r($form['field_rf_snaped_associated']);`

```
Array
(
[#type] => container
[#attributes] => Array
    (
        [class] => Array
            (
                [0] => field-type-list-text
                [1] => field-name-field-rf-snaped-associated
                [2] => field-widget-options-buttons
            )

    )

[#weight] => 14
[#tree] => 1
[#language] => und
[und] => Array
    (
        [#entity] => stdClass Object
            (
                [uid] => 1
                [name] => admin
                [type] => snaped_resource_finder
                [language] => und
                [title] => 
                [status] => 1
                [promote] => 1
                [sticky] => 0
                [created] => 1396239314
                [revision] => 
                [comment] => 2
                [menu] => Array
                    (
                        [link_title] => 
                        [mlid] => 0
                        [plid] => 0
                        [menu_name] => main-menu
                        [weight] => 0
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [module] => menu
                        [expanded] => 0
                        [hidden] => 0
                        [has_children] => 0
                        [customized] => 0
                        [parent_depth_limit] => 8
                    )

            )

        [#entity_type] => node
        [#bundle] => snaped_resource_finder
        [#field_name] => field_rf_snaped_associated
        [#language] => und
        [#field_parents] => Array
            (
            )

        [#columns] => Array
            (
                [0] => value
            )

        [#title] => Is this material associated with a SNAP-Ed program?
        [#description] => 
        [#required] => 1
        [#delta] => 0
        [#type] => radios
        [#default_value] => 
        [#options] => Array
            (
                [Yes] => Yes
                [No] => No
            )

        [#value_key] => value
        [#element_validate] => Array
            (
                [0] => options_field_widget_validate
            )

        [#properties] => Array
            (
                [filter_xss] => 1
                [strip_tags] => 
                [empty_option] => 
                [optgroups] => 
            )

        [#after_build] => Array
            (
                [0] => field_form_element_after_build
            )

    )

[#access] => 1
)
```

The first thing I noticed is that for each of those `[#type] => container` That's confusing. Drupal 7 form field API doesn't has very little to say about 'container' and I'm not sure how that plays into how this all works or not.

I also noticed that [#attributes][class][2](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/using-the-drupal-7-form-api-states-system-to-create-conditions-between-form-elements/2014-01-20) is a field name. I tried adding that as the :input[name=] value, but that didn't work either. Additionally, I tried to inspect element of the html form and use field_rf_snaped_associated[und] that was part of the HTML. But, no go either.

And, the one and final confusing point are some tutorials show `input[name...]` and other show `:input[name...].` But, whether I add or omit the colon, it makes no difference. Ultimately, here is the code I ended up with that I can't get to work.

```
function resourcefinder_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

// determine if we're on the correct form
if ($form_id == "snaped_resource_finder_node_form") {


    //dpm($form);
    //print_r($form["field_rf_which_state_territory"]);
    //print_r($form['field_rf_snaped_associated']);

    $form['field_rf_which_state_territory']['und']['0']['#states'] = array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="field_rf_snaped_associated[und]"]' => array('value' => 'Yes')
        ),
    );
}
}
```

So, how would I write that so field_rf_which_state_territory only shows up when 'Yes' is selected in the field_rf_snaped_associated field?

EDIT:
Screenshot showing dpm output of that field
[image]

Comment: I had exactly the same question, only with fields in an taxonomy term edit form. I had a select list (field_my_select) and a textfield I wanted to show (field_my_textfield). In the end I used following code in my custom module:  
    `function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state, $form_id){
  
if($form_id == 'taxonomy_form_term'){
    
    $form['field_my_textfield']['#states']= array(
        'visible' => array(  
          ':input[name="field_myselect[und]"]' => array('value' => (string)'0')
        ),
      
    );  
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
$form['field_rf_which_state_territory']['und']['0']['value']['#states'] = array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="field_rf_snaped_associated[und]"]' => array('value' => 'Yes')
        ),
```

When looking though the $form array you need to make sure that you are adding the #states array at the same level that the #type element appears.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the screenshot. Please see my edit. I added a screenshot as well for my dpm of that field. I have several #types within the hierarchy of the array. Additionally, I don't have a 'value' field like you do. Given my dump, what would you suggest the structure be?

Comment: Looking at your dmp output I would say you need $form['field_rf_which_state_territory']['und']['#states'] = ...